# FileZilla server on Windows with IIS and NEW folder / file permissions

Tags: web-hosting, ftp, windows

I am using FileZilla server on Windows 2008.
The service runs under the Local System account at the moment.

IIS isn't able to create files (eg for cache) or folders in these FileZilla created folders which causes problems.

How should I configure FileZilla or the service (or something else) to allow IIS and FileZilla to work together better in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't filezilla problem, you must set permission for parent folder of your sites home directory.
If you have a HOSTING folder which all sites home directory created under it by FileZilla, it must have permission for IIS_USR or NETWORK Service or any other users which must has write permission.

Comment: Do you mean the group "IIS_IUSRS"?

Comment: yes, by default this group must have permission on web folders

Answer (score 0):

I don't configure Filezilla on IIS. I just download FIlezilla on my local computer and then connect to IIS from Filezilla. It is easier and simpler.